# DashDB DB2 UNIQUE with NULL values

Tags: db2, nullable, unique-constraint, dashdb

it does not seem to be possible to declare a NULLABLE column, and to create a UNIQUE constraint.
Is there a way to deal with this case?
I need a column that can contain NULL values or UNIQUE values.
Maybe a trigger could do this?
Thanks

I'm using DashDB

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention your DB2 platform and version...that could make a difference.

But try adding a `UNIQUE WHERE NOT NULL` index..

`CREATE UNIQUE WHERE NOT NULL INDEX myindex ON mytable (columnn1)`

Comment: Version is DashDB on IBM Bluemix cloud (don't know which version it is exactly).

Comment: Actually I've noticed an error in my question I previously wrote "index" but I meant "constraint"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible - check out the option

> EXCLUDE NULL KEYS

in the CREATE INDEX syntax [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000919.html)

Comment: Actually I've noticed an error in my question I previously wrote "index" but I meant "constraint"

Comment: Currently you can't do this with a unique constraint. However since a unique constraint is a logical construct (its physical implementation is enforced via a unique index), creating the unique index as @MichaelTiefenbacher suggests will result in the same effect.